# Check if the call is diverted

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I wanted to make a program deals with the incoming phone calls ( answer, decline , mute , etc.. ) and i found a good example for this https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/

this [Example](https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/) contains a broadcast receiver which receives any incoming.
Now my ambition increased and i want to know how can i check if the incoming call is diverted because the diverted calls will come from my business phone number and i need to know before answering.

Comment: You should add a bounty to this question .. I want to know the answer too..